# Error 1067 invalid default value for EndDate

Tags: mysql

Can somebody tell me what I'm missing on this query? It keeps coming up with :

> Error 1067: invalid default value for `EndDate`

```
CREATE TABLE `course_info`(
`student_id` VARCHAR (35),
`course_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`name`      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`module`    VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`StartDate` TIMESTAMP,
`EndDate`   TIMESTAMP,  
`course_Update` TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY(`course_id`),
 FOREIGN KEY(`student_id`)
 REFERENCES student(`student_id`)
 )
 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can understand the reason of your error from the official [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date):

> The NO_ZERO_DATE mode affects whether the server permits '0000-00-00'
>   as a valid date. Its effect also depends on whether strict SQL mode is
>   enabled.
>
> - If this mode is not enabled, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce no warning.
> - If this mode is enabled, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce a warning.
> - If this mode and strict mode are enabled, '0000-00-00' is not permitted and inserts produce an error, unless IGNORE is given as
>     well. For INSERT IGNORE and UPDATE IGNORE, '0000-00-00' is permitted
>     and inserts produce a warning.

As it says, you can insert `0000-00-00` dates with `IGNORE` option. That's for insertion.

In your case, all what you have to do is to add the `NOT NULL` constraint to your `TIMESTAMP` fields in order to avoid the default value `0000-00-00` as follows:

```
StartDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
EndDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
course_Update TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
```

**EDIT 1:**

Following your comment, you need to edit my.cnf file if you are on Linux or my.ini file if you are on Windows to enable the strict SQL mode. You will find how to do that on [SQL-mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-mode.html)

Comment: i did what you  told me to do but it still coming up with the same error. :S

Comment: @Edrian just by declaring your table as you said on your question and you got the same error ?

Comment: @Edrian are you using linux or windows ?