# #1067 - Invalid default value for 'LastUpdated'

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, mysql-workbench

I made my ER diagram via MySQL WorkBench and exported it as a sql. Below is code for one table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xxx`.`Agent` (
  `idAgent` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `RegistrationNumber` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `RegistrationDate` DATE NULL,
  `DateOfDealStart` DATE NULL,
  `AddressLine1` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `AddressLine2` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `Country` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `CurrentStatus` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `DateCreated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `LastUpdated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idAgent`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

However when I am trying to import the script into MySQL via PhpMyAdmin, it says below.

```
#1067 - Invalid default value for 'LastUpdated'
```

I have not provided any default value, so how can it could be "Invalid"?

Comment: try the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005766/invalid-default-value-for-dateadded

Comment: @TarynEast: He has already provided a `default value`

Comment: Note: I got the above by googling "1067 Invalid default value for  date"

Comment: Fair enough. i didn't spot that

Comment: Maybe you have to provide a default?

Comment: @TarynEast: Maybe, but why?

Comment: Looks like this one has no provided default: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076899/error-1067-invalid-default-value-for-enddate (and an explanation of why it's a problem)

Comment: And another one, just in case that's not it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312144/error-error-1067-invalid-default-value-for-on-update-current-timestamp

Comment: no such error is generated when using rextexter.com